# Sharepoint list : Mandate a column based on value of another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, validation-list-items

I have a list "Budget Tracker" which has Budget Status, [Raised Date](Date & Time), [Approved Date](Date & Time), Expense Type and [Expense Details](single line item) as columns.
I want to have multiple validations like Approved date should be mandatory if Budget status is "Approved".
Expense Details should be mandatory if Budget status is "Approved and Expense Type is "True", etc
Is this doable, how do i execute this, please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? You can apply validations by doing form customizations on SharePoint list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following formulas in the list validation.

=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK[Expense Details]),[Budget status]="Approved"),TRUE)

=IF(AND([Expense Type]="True", [Budget status]="Approved"),TRUE)